# Iterate deep JSON in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to Iterate **JSON** in **jQuery**.
Using `$.each` i am trying to iterate.
I am trying but not getting result id and sizes of every user.

**JSON**

```
[
    [
        {
            "user": {
                "id": "8",
                "sizes": "65"
            }
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "user": {
                "id": "9",
                "sizes": "75"
            }
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "user": {
                "id": "10",
                "sizes": "85"
            }
        }
    ]
]
```

**My jQuery Script**

```
$.each (usersJson, function (key1, value1) {
    $. each (value1, function (key2, value2) {
        $. each (value2, function (key3, value3) {
            console.log(key3+"--"+value3);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Why is each user object in its own array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.each(usersJson, function (key, value) {
    var user = value[0].user;
    console.log(user.id, user.sizes);
});
```

You should not use nested loops when they can be avoided as they can greatly increase time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

use `id,sizes` as the key

```
 $.each (usersJson, function (key1, value1) {
    $. each (value1, function (key2, value2) {
        $. each (value2, function (key3, value3) {
            console.log(key3+"--"+value3.id);
             console.log(key3+"--"+value3.sizes);
        });
    });
});
```

OR use simplest this way

```
$.each(usersJson, function (key1, value1) {

    $.each(value1, function (key2, value2) {
        console.log(value2.user.id);
        console.log(value2.user.sizes);

    });
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6k8V/14/)

Answer (score 1):

You are one level too short:   Although technically your `users` do not need to be wrapped in an `array` as the currently are and then your code would work.

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/75FYK/

```
myJSON = [
    [{
        "user": {
            "id": "8",
                "sizes": "65"
        }
    }],
    [{
        "user": {
            "id": "9",
                "sizes": "75"
        }
    }],
    [{
        "user": {
            "id": "10",
                "sizes": "85"
        }
    }]
];

$.each(myJSON, function (key1, value1) {
    $.each(value1, function (key2, value2) {
        $.each(value2, function (key3, value3) {
            $.each(value3, function (key4, value4) {
                console.log(key4 + "--" + value4);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a recursive function, which would work for any depth and any combination of object, arrays, etc. :

```
(function dive(k,v){
  if (typeof v==="object") {
    for (var k in v) dive(k, v[k]);
  } else if (Array.isArray(v)) {
    for (var i=0; i<v.length; i++) dive(i, v[i]);
  } else {
    console.log(k+"--"+v);
  }
})("data",data);
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/kazixi/1/edit)

Answer (score 1):

For the first loop you are iterating over array but for second and third over an object.
Try to modify:

```
$.each (usersJson, function (k, v) {
    $.each (v, function (key1, value1) {
        for (key2 in value1) {
            for (key3 in value1[key2]) {
                console.log(key2 + '.' + key3 + "=" + value1[key2][key3]);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z6k8V/15/

Answer (score 1):

If there's any way you can adjust your JSON so that the objects are all in the same array and your values are integers rather than strings (although that's not a complete dealbreaker), life becomes much simpler:

```
var usersJson = [{
    id: 8,
    sizes: 65
}, {
    id: 9,
    sizes: 75
}, {
    id: 10,
    sizes: 85
}]

$.each(usersJson, function (index, obj) {
  console.log(obj.id, obj.sizes);
});
```